# C++ Structure Declaration and usage compiler error

Tags: c++, struct

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct product {
  int weight;
  float price;
} apple, banana, melon; // can I declare like this ?????

int main()
{
  apple a;

}
```

When I compiled this sample, the compiler says:

```
struct.cpp|11|error: expected ';' before 'a'|
```

Same thing works fine in C language ...

What's wrong?

Comment: Ignoring the C++ syntax in the header and namespace (which aren't needed to reproduce the problem with the almost minimal code you have here), the code would not compile in C, either.  While C and C++ are different languages, they are at least similar in that.

Answer (score 6):

What you've done is declared `apple`, `banana` and `melon` as global instances of `product` whereas your `main` function indicates that you wanted to declare them as types. To do this you would use the `typedef` keyword in the declaration. (Although why do you need so many synonyms for `struct product`?)

This is not different from C. The only difference between C and C++ in your example is that in C++ `product` names a type whereas in C you have to specify `struct product`. (Apart from the more obvious fact that you can't have `#include <iostream>` or `using namespace std;` in C.)

E.g., declares `apple`, `banana` and `melon` as synonyms for `struct product`:

```
typedef struct product {
  int weight;
  float price;
} apple, banana, melon;
```

Answer (score 1):

`apple` isn't a type, it's a variable of the `product` struct type you declared.

```
typedef product apple;
```

would create a type called `apple`.

Comment: That's pure C++; in C, you'd need `typedef struct product apple;`, of course.  Since the question is tagged C++ and not C, this a pure observation - not a criticism.

Answer (score 1):

No it doesn't. In C you would write

```
typedef struct product {
   int weight;
   float price;
} apple;
```

Note the `typedef`.

Answer (score 1):

How could the same code run in C? your code will give the same error in C also, it is incorrect.

in the main you have done: `apple a` where `apple` is not any type. It is a global `struct product` type variable.

To define a variable of your structure type do:

```
int main (void)
{
  struct product a;
}
```

Or if you want to name your struct with some name you can use `typedef` like

```
typedef struct product {
     int weight;
     float price;
} product;
```

and then

```
int main (void)
{
  product apple, a, whataver;
}
```